# Initialize char[] fails, esi contains wrong value

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I want to initialize a char array, but during I do this my programm crashes. Here's my code:

```
void kernelEnteredMsg() {
    char str[] = "Kernel successfully entered!";
}
```

Here's the disassembly:

```
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push edi
push esi
push ebx
sub esp,byte +0x30
lea edx,[ebp-0x2d]
mov ebx,0x402000 ; load an address outside my data segment
mov eax,0x1d
mov edi,edx
mov esi,ebx ; move this address to edi
mov ecx,eax
rep movsb ; here the programm crashes
add esp,byte +0x30
pop ebx
pop esi
pop edi
pop ebp
ret
```

I don't understand why it loads esi with 0x402000. But this seems to cause the error. Can somebody explain what happens here and how to fix it?

PS: "Kernel successful entered!" is at 0x1000 in binary file.

C code:

```
void kernelEnteredMsg();

void entryPoint() {
    kernelEnteredMsg();
}

void kernelEnteredMsg() {
    char str[] = "Kernel successfully entered!";
    int size = 28;
}
```

Calling assembly code:

```
extern _entryPoint
global _main
section .text
_main: ; start of kernel
nop
; setup ds, es, ss and gs
mov ax, 16
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x4000
mov ax, 24
mov gs, ax
mov [gs:0], dword 0x07690748 ; test graphics
call _entryPoint ; enter kernel C code
jmp $
```

Comment: In isolation, this C code cannot possibly cause a crash (unless your compiler/linker/runtime is broken).  You must be invoking undefined behaviour elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth How much code you need?

Comment: @kaetzacoatl It's not really a question of "how much"... We need the code that causes the crash.

Comment: @kaetzacoatl: I suggest constructing a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth added the whole executed code

Comment: @kaetzacoatl Again, it doesn't make sense that this code crashes. What error are you getting?

Comment: Presumably you are linking or loading it wrong. The gcc compiler usually puts the string literal into the section `.rodata`, the link address of which probably doesn't match where you have loaded it.

Comment: @Jester there isn't a .rodata section in any of my files, but the string literal is in .rdata

Comment: Same deal. You are linking or loading wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This code does copy the string from the .text section to the local stack, because the char array is not 'const'. This may provide a simple solution if you do not need the string to be modified - just make it const char.

> I don't understand why it loads esi with 0x402000.

ESI is the source of the string copy instruction 'rep movsb', EDI is the destination.
The address is constructed by IMAGE_BASE+SECTION (IIRC) in the PE file(assuming it is PE.)
Remember in the file there is a FILE_ALIGN and a SECTION_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS, so a section may be
at position 0x1000 in the file(FILE_ALIGN) and at 0x2000 in memory(VIRTUAL_ADDRESS) resulting in IMAGE_BASE+VIRTUAL_ADDRESS=0x402000.

You can use a PE explorer like CFF Explorer(http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) 
to display this(if it's a .bin file it may be unapplicable but it has to have some kind of format)

Another possibility may be a wrong state of the DF-Flag leading to wrong behaviour of the string copy instruction (should not happen, because the compiler should take care of this).

Try inserting

```
__asm__ ("cld");
```

before the char str[] or in the __main procedure to set string increment to 'UP'.

Comment: Is it possible to tell gcc where the data is stored?

Comment: Don't know that for gcc, but file sections in PE files have arbitrary names and attrbiutes. Usually the .text-section or .rdata-section is read-only and used for constants(see first paragraph of my answer). If you would declare the char str[] as a global variable it should be put in the .data-section which is read-write and therefore no copying to the stack would be neccessary. The section names are just conventions and may change depending on the compiler(and version) used.

Comment: Well, one addition. The whole thing about sections depends on the environment(the OperatingSystem), because it does the section loading from disk to memory. If, for example, you're trying to write a simple bootloader or kernel yourself - and manually setting up ds,es,fs,gs suggests that - you would have to do that manually, because the are no sections(yet) - gcc just assumes an (specific) environment which does no neccessarily match the factually present one.

Comment: I now use "..."-0x401000, this isn't a nice solution but it works. I cannot load the string to 0x402000, because this memory location is outside my current data segment. But thank you for this answer.

Comment: `const` has **nothing** to do with it being copied. `static` would change the variable from being a local on the stack, to one that is always referenced from the data section.